# [Sybase][ODBC Driver][Adaptive Server Enterprise]SET CHAINED command not allowed within multi-statement transaction.\n (226) (SQLExecDirectW);

Tags: database, robotframework, sybase, sap-ase

Using the robot-framework to connect with Sybase DB 
Then DELETE row, UPDATE row in a TABLE.

When the below query is executed in robot framework, it works fine.

**Sybase DB Connection - Delete and Update for a single pass**

```
connect To Database Using Custom Params    pyodbc    "Driver={Adaptive Server Enterprise}; server=<myserver>; port=<myport>;db=<mydb>;uid=<myuser>; pwd=<mypasswd>;"
# Run Select Query
@{selectQuery}    Query    select * from TABLE where FIELD1 = '1000'
Log Many    @{selectQuery}
Log    "Selected Query Executed"
# Run Delete Query
@{DeleteQuery}    Execute Sql String    set chained off ; Delete from TABLE where FIELD1 = '1000' AND FIELD2 = 'VALUE2' AND FIELD3 = 'VALUE3'
Log Many    @{DeleteQuery}
Log    "Delete Query Executed"
#Run Update Query
@{updateQuery}    Execute Sql String    set chained off ; UPDATE TABLE SET FIELD2 = 'VALUE2' where FIELD1 = '1001'
Log Many    @{updateQuery}
Log    "Update Query Executed"
Disconnect From Database
```

Whereas when the for loop is used as below :

**Sybase DB Connection - Delete with for loop for mutliple passes**

```
connect To Database Using Custom Params    pyodbc    "Driver={Adaptive Server Enterprise}; server=<myserver>; port=<myport>;db=<mydb>;uid=<myuser>; pwd=<mypasswd>;"
#Run DELETE Query
:FOR    ${num}    IN RANGE    100
\    Execute Sql String    set chained off ; Delete from TABLE where FIELD1 = ${num} and FIELD2= "${VALUE2[${num}]}" and FIELD3 = "${VALUE3[${num}]}"
\    sleep    1
```

It fails with the below error :

```
[Sybase][ODBC Driver][Adaptive Server Enterprise]SET CHAINED command not allowed within multi-statement transaction.\n (226) (SQLExecDirectW);

[Sybase][ODBC Driver][Adaptive Server Enterprise]Stored procedure 'abc_sp' may be run only in unchained transaction mode. The 'SET CHAINED OFF' command will cause the current session to use unchained transaction mode.\n (7713)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Used the **commit**

The below for loop worked fine.

```
connect To Database Using Custom Params    pyodbc    "Driver={Adaptive Server Enterprise}; server=<myserver>; port=<myport>;db=<mydb>;uid=<myuser>; pwd=<mypasswd>;"

#Run DELETE Query
:FOR    ${num}    IN RANGE    100
\    Execute Sql String    commit
\    Execute Sql String    set chained off ; Delete from TABLE where FIELD1 = ${num} and FIELD2= "${VALUE2[${num}]}" and FIELD3 = "${VALUE3[${num}]}"
\    Execute Sql String    commit
```